# Need to get page loaded on the same page (Half page)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

```
    <html>
    <form method="get" action="/00ON0000000FOHS" >
        <b>Enter Text</b><input type="text" id="pv2" name="pv2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Report Generation" class="submit"/>
   </form> 
   </html>
```

i want get the action page to get loaded on the same page which input box is there

Like above half of the page is user input.and below half of the page will be loaded according to user input.

Comment: Do you want to show two separate pages on the same window?

Comment: same window ,same page two separate block ,one block is static that user input side,another one is dynamic

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy and elegant using jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#results").load(form.attr("action"), form.serialize());
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="/00ON0000000FOHS" >
        <b>Enter Text</b><input type="text" id="pv2" name="pv2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Report Generation" class="submit"/>
    </form> 
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/syndicatedshannon/2WE54/

Notes:

- **The jsfiddle doesn't return anything because there is no page at the action URL.** The word "Result" that you see is not part of the example, but an overlay from the jsfiddle.net site. To see that it is working, open the site in Chrome, open the Developer Tools (F12), switch to the network panel, submit the form, click on the new resource that appeared in the network panel, and select the headers tab.
- The jsfiddle.net site automatically incorporates jQuery and the HTML tag for you, but you need to include these yourself, as per the above code snippet. You might choose to change the jQuery source to another CDN.
- jQuery.load() is a shorthand "helper" method that performs an HTTP GET. There are helper methods for POST as well, but you should probably read about the full range of jQuery AJAX methods, here: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
- The example I've provided uses the URL from the form's `action` attribute. Two benefits to this: the URL is only defined in one place and your interaction functions when JavaScript is disabled. This is an old and well-trusted technique for this, but if you can assume certain things about your browsers, other approaches can be used.
- You mention IFRAME in your original question tags. In most cases you'll want to avoid IFRAME, as it adds various complications. The `<div id="results"></div>` in the example plays the role of what you are thinking of using an IFRAME for. This is the normal way to perform partial-page updates today.
- This element-update technique could add complexity to your server-side code if you do wish to support plain (non-AJAX) requests to the same URL. You might choose to use a different `<form action=` to keep things simpler in this case. It is also fairly common to detect at the server when the request is not AJAX, and then wrap the response in a page template.
- CSS is reponsible for allocating the space on the page, and providing the "change in-place without disturbing anything else". I've provided a simple example of CSS for that here. The `#results` container has a `position: relative;` attribute, causing children to be fairly well contained in it, although it doesn't prevent objects with offsets that would put them outside their parent containers from doing so. You may wish to ask a separate question about CSS if this is a problem for you.
- You can easily find additional information about this. It is surely a duplicate question here on stack overflow, although there are so many questions on the topic I couldn't find an exact, well-worded match for you. To see related topics, search for keywords jQuery.load, AJAX submit, and partial-page update to name a few.

Comment: i need to get load the results in the half of the page i need that in such a way that half page is static which is user input section and remain half page is dynamic (which is the results section).

Comment: when i clicked the report generation it is reloading into the results page

Comment: That's simply a question of CSS, my friend. Here, let me update the working example for you to demonstrate.

Comment: k Shannon i will check it out

Comment: Hi shannon ,still wheni click submit it is reloading to results page.any other ideas are there

Comment: Are you talking about the working example link I've provided you, or code that you've copied and run on your own site?

Comment: tejdeep, notice the first comment I made when I first posted the example. I've bolded it above. The example does not return any results, because there is no server to offer results at the URL `/00ON0000000FOHS`. You can change this URL to something else, such as `/`, if you wish, but there are security rules that prevent you from requesting documents from outside sources. Please make an effort and try this code on your own.

Comment: What results would you expect to return in the jsfiddle example? Something from your website? If you change the `<form action=` URL to `/echo/json/` you will get back a result of `{}`. This may satisfy you that it is working. Your next step is to try it on your own server.

Comment: shannon i had kept the code in the in the text pad and i had kept the action as google.com.when i click submit it is not loading the google page.

Comment: ya google page came but it it is not coming in the div tag it is coming as a whole page

Comment: 1) I'm not sure what browser you are using that is allowing you to bypass google's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, but Chrome will not return any result if you try to submit your form to Google. 2) You may wish to re-read the notes I made for you above. I mentioned the simple CSS I provided "doesn't prevent objects with offsets that would put them outside their parent containers from doing so". 3) You are putting content on your page that you do not control, so you should not be surprised it is doing something you do not wish. Please try this on your own server.

Comment: At this point, tejdeep, until you are willing to make the effort to actually try this on your own, I'm afraid I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 0):

Try ajax.
Please see link: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

in the url: you can set a php or any other server side page to call.

In that server side page write your php code and echo the result, it will return the value on the page from where you are calling the ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "server side page link",
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $('div#id').html(data);<==== it will show you data what has been echoed on the server side page
  });
```